# How to restrict multiple logins using same account without using databse in php?

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I am working on a web application where user's are supposed to enter their user name and password and enter into their account. I need to put the following restrictions on the application:

- Restrict multiple logins in the same account from either same or different ip addresses.
- Restrict logins to the same or different accounts from the same IP address.

I dont want to make use of any databases here. So is there any possible way to do it with PHP alone ??

Comment: Why don't you want to use the database? The best way to do so is the database.

Comment: ... You have to store the data *somewhere*. And no, I don't see how writing to a file is different from using a DB, aside the fact it's slower. Have you considered SQLite, or some other lightweight db?

Comment: If you wont use a database how are you storing the username and password details that you verify against?

Comment: I don't want to use db because of the latency issue.....my internet connection bandwidth and speed is low...and using a database is going to slow down the process i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i know how to do this is to bind the logged-in users session to their USER-AGENT and IP address and username.

Store the hashed value of USER-AGENT and IP and username of the users in their session and each time  checking the session to see if the user is logged in compare the hashed value of USER-AGENT and IP address and username of the current user with the one in the session and if its not the same destroy the session data and ask for re-login.

UPDATE:

this method would mostly prevent session highjacking but to keep out multiple users with same username you have to store something unique of them in a db field.
Store the session_id when user logs in in users db table.
when checking  if user is logged in (in every page request i assume) compare the session_id of the user with the one id db and if they don't mach destroy the session , delete the session_id from db and redirect the user to login page.

NOTICE:

if you don't want to use db you have to store a list of username/session_id's in a file

Comment: What if I have two active sessions? Each one from a different IP and a different User-Agent.

Comment: Session relies on the user sending a cookie. If the user doesn't send that cookie, the whole thing fails, and this is supposed to be part of a protection scheme. Besides, user agent? The user agent string is reported by the browser, and, again, it's the easiest thing to fake it.

Comment: i know but its really hard/impossible to so this without a db

Comment: @SáT but how do you keep the user logged in if they dont send any session_id(stored in cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You have to save something from the user to identificate him. For example the session_id. If you don't want to save it in a database, then you have to save it for example in a file.

You could create a file for each user and save the sessionID in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data of the logged in people in a file, then when a user tried to log in just check against the data in the file